# Nginx + Gunicorn + Flask = can only access web app via port domain.com:5555

Tags: nginx, flask, gunicorn

I followed the instructions here exactly: 
http://www.onurguzel.com/how-to-run-flask-applications-with-nginx-using-gunicorn/

Everything seems to be running except that when I go to domain.com, my site does not load. Only when I go to domain:5555, where flask is setup to run, can I access my site.

Is this because my flask is setup in debug mode?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5555, debug=True)
```

Comment: I think nginx is listening on 80....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you did the config just like described in the post, then you need to replace this

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
```

with this

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5555;
```

Not really the best nginx config I've seen it uses 'if' and [If Is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), I'll rewrite this config for you when I have a spare min, just make sure it works after this change first, don't forget to run

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

---

**EDIT**: sorry I forgot about this, here's my replacement for the `if` part

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

You can try it and tell me how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The `app.run()` method of running the application that you are using does not use gunicorn nor nginx, that's running Flask's development web server.

Go back to the page you refer to and reread the part about starting the app with gunicorn. Once you have the app running with gunicorn, which you can test by opening `http://127.0.0.1:8000` (from your server, not from the outside) then start nginx with the config they give and that will expose the app on your domain as you expect.